# How to display several pages of a PDF simultaneously in Docview?

Tags: preview-latex, docview

I'm using Emacs, AUCTeX, and `latex-preview-pane-mode` to create a PDF presentation. However, the preview only displays one page at a time.
Is this the only way? It wastes some of the vertical space available on the screen.

Is it possible for Docview to preview several pages of a PDF in one page?

Comment: How about `(setq doc-view-continuous t)` and then (if needed) shrink the size of the pages that are visible?

Comment: @lawlist: At least for me, all that does is let `C-n` and `C-p` move between pages. While that's quite handy, it still only displays one page at a time.

Comment: I see -- after some Googling, it looks like your feature has been an ongoing discussion on the Emacs mailing lists for several years, but I don't think that feature exists yet.

Comment: I don't remember this specific functionality being discussed, but it would actually make a lot of sense for doc-view-continuous to behave like you want (i.e. just display all the pages one below the other).  You should probably request it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you are using doc-view in windows 7, can you share how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for displaying several images in the same window, so there are two workarounds:

- split the right window to display two slides at the same time.  As there is no way to send commands to two windows at the same time this is rather pointless, though, as one of the windows will stay fixed when you press `n` or `p` in the other window.  You might be able to overwrite this, but it seems messy.
- you could try to affect the pdf-to-image conversion.  While ghostscript itself does not seem to allow rendering multiple pages to the same image file you may be able to replace the ghostscript executable (by setting `doc-view-ghostscript-program`) with a wrapper that calls ghostscript and then zips up the images in pairs, e.g. with ImageMagick's `montage`.

Neither of these two methods is particularly appealing.

Unfortunately, `mudraw` (which can be used as an alternative renderer) also does not support rendering multiple pages to the same image file.